# Win32: Work-around for GetFileAttributes()

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winapi

I'm noticing a problem that has crept up a few times over the years, and seems to be happening a lot under Windows 7 in our current build.

When I test for the existence of a file, using ::GetFileAttributes(filename), I am often getting back INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES, and GetLastError() is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND (3).

However, the file does exist, the path exists, the volume exists - its H:\Foo\Bar - which is a folder on a network share that is mapped on my machine to H:.

If I open a command window, it can see it.  If I use Windows Explorer to navigate to that folder, it can see it.

If I do those before running our app, we can see it.

But if I run our app first, after a reboot, before anything has attempted to view H:\, then I get the above error repeatedly.

It has always seemed to me that Windows is "helping" me by returning ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND immediately when the given share-mapping hasn't been reconnected this session (it is set to auto-reconnect).  This is, needless to say, annoying.  Is there another API call I could be making to "determine if file/folder X exists?"

Comment: I don't think the bug is related to your network going out as you'd get a different error code.  Try logging the filename to a file and the return result each time.  Maybe you'll find the path is invalid sometimes because of corrupted memory or maybe blank path.

Comment: I am running this in my development environment.  I can see the path is valid, and the return code is consistently 3.  The LAN is configured as a simple peer-to-peer system, and the "server" is a simple XP Pro box, with an unprotected share (internally, D:\Home Folders).  This system has worked for years, except that occasionally I would get that error, and always it clears up if I simply access the mapped drive before running our application (or before loading the dev env to run in debug mode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running the application as a service? Or as some other user? It may be a permissions issue. The credentials it's using may not have permission to read that directory.

Comment: Running as my developer (admin) login on a Windows 7 x64 Business machine (I am a local admin, no domain involved).

Comment: I think you were right.  I had to allow VS2008 restart "with additional permissions" several sessions recently as I have been debugging our installer.  So this is probably a different user-identity, one that doesn't have H: mapped.  Seems like a bug in Win7 (maybe also Vista), since elevating privileges shouldn't cause the app to no longer see the same drives as the user for whom it was elevated...

Comment: Confirmed: restarting the PC & immediately running a retail copy of our app, or debugging it with non-elevated permissions, resulted in correct behavior (file & path found).

Comment: @Mordachai Actually, elevating privileges does indeed cause the app to no longer see the same drives because Windows considers it two different sessions when UAC is enabled.  More details in this article: [Some Programs Cannot Access Network Locations When UAC Is Enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(WS.10).aspx).  As the article mentions, there's a registry tweak to make Windows copy mapped drives between elevated and non-elevated sessions.

Answer (score 3):

The drive connection needs to be restored, that's done automatically by the shell.  It used to be done by WNetRestoreConnectionW() but that function has been removed in Vista.  I think you'll need to do it [this way now](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/29163328-21d7-40d8-a68b-5c8d24e41e05).

Using a UNC path (`\\share\dir\file`) might be the better cure.

Comment: Thanks.  I have seen the behavior I originally posted about over the years, and this article sounds like it might allow me to fix that aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use `ShellExecuteEx` with the flag `SEE_MASK_CONNECTNETDRV`.

Comment: What would I be executing?  I'm looking for the existence of a file, not running anything...